# use of undeclared identifier self

Tags: objective-c, ios

I created a class named Data parsing and in this class, I laid out three functions:

The first is `getData()`, and it needs to call `parseLine()`.

I am calling the `parseLine()` method like so:

```
[self parseline];
```

However, I am receiving the following error:

```
Sse of undeclared identifier 'self'
```

How are my functions in this class suppose to call each other?

```
void getData(NSString *data) { 
    while(temp_top < [data length]) { 
        icc_data[++data_top] = [data characterAtIndex:temp_top]; 
        if (icc_data[data_top]==')' && icc_data[data_top -1]=='\031') { } 
        if (icc_data[0]!='\031' && icc_data[data_top]=='\n') { 
            [dataParsing parseLine]; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you make getData a class method (does the function def have a + before it)?

Comment: Please post a small code snippet.

Comment: #import "dataParsing.h"

@implementation dataParsing

void getData(NSString *data)
{
  while(temp_top < [data length])
  {
      
      icc_data[++data_top] = [data characterAtIndex:temp_top];
      if (icc_data[data_top]==')' && icc_data[data_top -1]=='\031')
      {
          
      }
      if (icc_data[0]!='\031' && icc_data[data_top]=='\n')
      {
          [dataParsing parseLine];

Comment: the [dataParsing parsline] was an experiment if i could do something other than self.

Comment: it's sounding like i havent properly declared it as a class. i did actually not add it to the .h , i wasnt sure i had to. if i had it to the .h will it work with self?

Comment: Please edit the code snippet into the question and use the `{}` icon to format it as code.

Comment: @KeithThompson consider it done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are implementing `void getData(NSString *data)` as a C function. Functions do not get a reference to `self`. Use a method instead:

```
- (void)data
{
}
```

Comment: get exepct method body @implementation dataParsing

-(void)getData(NSString *data)
{

Answer (score 2):

To use C functions just call it normally:

```
getData(myData);
```

If you implement it as an Objective C method like:

```
- (void)getData:(NSString *)data
{
     //Code
}
```

then you call this using `self`:

```
[self getData:myData];
```

Comment: got it working. its in the .h and .m as a class method now. useful trick.

Comment: i would check both answers as useful but only lets me check one. so top answer got it