# use of undeclared identifier self in performSelector Error

Tags: objective-c, selector, self

I want to call the function playSound with the object temp_filename after the delay.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(playSound:) withObject:(temp_filename) afterDelay:time];
```

But I am getting the error message below.

> "use of undeclared identifier self"

Comment: possible duplicate of [use of undeclared identifier self](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12790880/use-of-undeclared-identifier-self)

Comment: I didn't find it useful :-(

Comment: How are you calling this method? Post the place it is getting called in, the full method.